# How to export lib incorporated with C dynllib?

Tags: rust, shared-libraries, rust-cargo

Say, I have a lib package with a C shared library in a sub-directory. This rust library package compiles without errors, by means of tailored `build.rs` which sub-calls `make` in the sub-directory and then dynamicly links against the `*.so` product of `make`.

The problem arises when I try to link a binary package against this rust lib has the C shared lib within itself.

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda_wrapper
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The dependency graph can be shown as the following one:

```
C-shared-lib < rust-lib < rust-bin
```

And `cargo build` fails to build `rust-bin` for not finding that `C-shared-lib`.

providing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for `cargo build` neither by command line nor `build.rs` within `rust-bin` facilitates the problem and lifts the error.

How to propagate the directory wherein resides `libcuda_wrapper.so`?

Comment: Did you try enabling [rpath](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#rpath)?

Comment: @rodrigo, I have added it, but changes nothing. only `"-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../../../../../../../.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2021-11-07-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib"` this path is added

Comment: What about adding `#![link_args="-Wl,-rpath /path/to/where/libcuda/is"]` to the top of your `lib.rs`?

Comment: @rodrigo, it would be a relative path, but what file regarding?

Comment: @rodrigo, or, at a guess, you mean placing it just above `#[link(name = "cuda_wrapper")]` ?

Comment: @rodrigo, `error: cannot find attribute `link_args` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:1:4
  |
1 | #![link_args="-Wl,-rpath,/cpp_v2"]
  |    ^^^^^^^^^ help: a built-in attribute with a similar name exists: `linkage`
`

Comment: Oh, I think it is an old name for that unstable `linkage` attribute. I got it from this [old issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5077). Maybe you can try other ways from there to set that rpath thing. Alternatively you could try adding the directory where the so resides to the native search path when linking the final binary, something like a `build.rs` that does `println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", so_dir);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can link your C library dynamically or statically.
In order to do that you can use add one of the following lines to your build.rs (note that you linkely won't need a lib prefix):

```rust
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=cuda_wrapper");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=cuda_wrapper");
```

In order to define a search path, add this line to build.rs

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", path);
```

You would likely want to add it to your rust-lib build.rs. Altenatively, you can create a build.rs for every executable which depends on rust-bin and add the same set of lines here.

It is a good idea to ensure that your C library build output is located under OUT_DIR env variable (you can get it using `env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap()` in build.rs). The way cargo clean will work as expected as well.

More details here:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rustc-link-lib
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html#option-l-link-lib
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-script-examples.html#building-a-native-library
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html

Comment: it does not work. I works only if it is a binary itself, not library, if it is a library it works for tests of this lib, but not for a binary which depends on this library. I guess it might work for static linking, but the case is about the dynamic one.